# ¿Cómo unir dos Querys que tienen un SELECT compuesto por un COUNT y LEFT JOIN? Se consultan tres tablas distintas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tres tablas en mi BD:

1. dependencias: lista de dependencias de la empresa.
2. dep_x_doc: documentos asignados a la dependencia como usuaria.
3. dep_r_x_doc: documentos asignados a la dependencia como responsable.

El resultado esperado de la consulta es que me muestre la cantidad de documentos asignados a la dependencia como usuaria y como responsable. Sin embargo el resultado no es el correcto.

Si ejecuto los Querys por separado el resultado sí es correcto:

Query que me trae la cantidad de Documentos Asignados como Usuaria por dependencia:

```
SELECT d.id, d.descripcion, COUNT(u.iddependencia) AS Usuaria
FROM dependencias d
LEFT JOIN dep_x_doc u ON d.id = u.iddependencia 
WHERE d.estructura = '1' and d.estado = 'A' 
GROUP BY d.id 
ORDER BY d.id ASC;
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado del query de documentos asignados como usuaria]

Query que me trae la cantidad de Documentos Asignados como Responsable por dependencia:

```
SELECT d.id, d.descripcion,  COUNT(r.iddependencia) AS Responsable
FROM dependencias d
LEFT JOIN dep_r_x_doc r ON d.id = r.iddependencia
WHERE d.estructura = '1' and d.estado = 'A' 
GROUP BY d.id 
ORDER BY d.id ASC;
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado del query de documentos asignados como responsable]

Pero cuando creo y ejecuto el query completo, el resultado no es el correcto o esperado:

Query completo creado:

```
SELECT d.id, d.descripcion, COUNT(u.iddependencia) AS Usuaria, COUNT(r.iddependencia) AS Responsable
FROM dependencias d
LEFT JOIN dep_x_doc u ON d.id = u.iddependencia
LEFT JOIN dep_r_x_doc r ON d.id = r.iddependencia
WHERE d.estructura = '1' and d.estado = 'A' 
GROUP BY d.id 
ORDER BY d.id ASC;
```

Resultado erróneo del Query completo:

[image: Resultado del query completo]

Como pueden ver, el conteo de documentos asignados tanto como Dependencia Usuaria y como Dependencia Responsable no es el correcto, de acuerdo a los querys por separado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logré encontrar una solución, así quedaría el query completo:

```
SELECT d.id, d.descripcion, COUNT(DISTINCT u.iddoc) AS Usuaria, COUNT(DISTINCT r.iddoc) AS Responsable
FROM dependencias d
LEFT JOIN dep_x_doc u ON d.id = u.iddependencia
LEFT JOIN dep_r_x_doc r ON d.id = r.iddependencia
WHERE d.estructura = '1' and d.estado = 'A'
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY d.id ASC;
```

Las modificaciones que le hice son las siguientes:

1. Cambié en cada `COUNT` el código de la dependencia, por el código del documento, de manera tal que me cuente cada documento asignado.
2. Agregué un `DISTINCT` dentro de cada `COUNT` para evitar o filtrar datos duplicados en el agrupamiento.  Creo que puede existir una explicación más técnica sobre el uso del `DISTINCT` en éste caso particular, sin embargo, es lo que de momento logro entender.

> Si alguien puede ampliar mas mi respuesta sobre éste punto lo agradecería mucho.

Acá el resultado del QUERY:

[image: Resultado correcto del query]

Acá les muestro como se ve el mantenimiento en el front:

[image: Vista del mantenimiento en el front]

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.